# How to save an image of an active window when X server is not running

Tags: ssh

I have a computer in remote location that I prefer to use as a server. I always keep the lid closed, and it is set to always keep running while the screen is off. Because I use this server to run software. I want to take screenshots to stay up to date of my apps that are running. I am wondering if there is a way to save an image, of an active window, when X server is not running.

Update: `ps -e | grep X` outputs PID: 581 for Xorg. So my Xserver is running.

Update: I am not using X11 forwarding.

Update: I need, if possible, to take a screenshot of the active window (firefox) on my remote machine. Save that screenshot on my remote machine then get it with `scp host1:/path/to/screenshot/ localhost:/destinationfile`

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to best use this site. Do you mean like you want to be able to take screenshots when there is no graphical environment running or you want a "snapshot" of what processes/services/etc are currently running on your computer at a given moment? Please update your post to clarify on these details. Thank you!

Comment: How do you have an X window, without an X server?

Comment: @kemotep I want to take a screenshot when there is no graphical environment running. I just updated my post, stating that Xorg is in fact running. Thank you

Comment: @Kornee So are you using x11 forwarding when you ssh in? I just want to know if it would be easier to take screenshots of your remote desktop screen on your host vs if the screenshots need to originate or be saved on the remote laptop. Please edit your post to include where you want the screenshots saved (host/remote) and how you specifically connect to your remote device (what remote desktop software you are using). Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep I just updated my post. Citing that I am not using x11 forwarding, that I need to save the screenshot on my remote machine. Then I will get my screenshot with `scp remote_host:/path/to/screenshot localhost:/destinationfile`
The reason I am doing this is that I use my iPhone to ssh to my remote machine. So x11 forwarding will be of no use. I think.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a utility like [`scrot`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/scrot/scrot.1.en.html).

Once you `ssh` into your remote computer you can run the following:

```
scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'mv $f /home/user/shots/'
```

This command will take a screenshot of your current screen with the filename of `YEAR-MONTH-DAY_SCREENWIDTH_SCREENHEIGHT.png` and move the file to your `/shots` directory (if you have one). If you need to run this at regular intervals without your input you could create a [cronjob](https://www.taniarascia.com/setting-up-a-basic-cron-job-in-linux/).

Create a bash script with the command you want to run. If you wanted to run the command every hour it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scrot '%Y-%m-%d-%H.png' -e 'mv $f /home/user/screenshots/'
```

And save this file in an appropriate location like `/home/user/scripts` and make it executable (`chmod +x screenshot.sh`)

Your user's crontab should contain this line if you want it to run every hour (run `crontab -e` to edit your user's crontab):

```
1 * * * * /home/user/scripts/screenshot.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will execute `screenshot.sh` at the first minute of every hour.

Alternatively you can save your script into `/etc/cron.hourly` to have it run hourly.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/2371) is a relevant post about working with crontab that you should check out.

Test to make sure that `scrot` works acceptably for your needs and also that your cronjob works correctly. You can then further automate the process to automatically email you the picture or push the picture to your computer with `scp`.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have things running in X, then X is still running. Killing X would kill most programs that are using it.

So, you can do a few things(remember you will need to set your DISPLAY variable on a remote term like `DISPLAY=:0`):

1. Imagemagick has a utility called 'import' and running `import -window root screenshot.png` will give you a screenshot.
2. scrot can take a screenshot, but I don't know the command line
3. x11vnc can give you vnc access to a running X display

Comment: I already have an active window (firefox to be precise) on my server. I just updated my post stating that Xorg is in fact running. What I want to do, is be able to take a screenshot of firefox window on my server. Thank you